# Eclipse, cannot create cxf Soap server

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, wsdl, cxf

I had a soap web service running and configured in my workspace created from an wsdl using the built-in procedure. I had to delete it for some reasons, but now I'm unable to create it again, I'm using the exact same procedure as before but I receive some errors.

Here's the procedure: create a dynamic web project (set tomcat 7 as target runtime, 2.5 as dynamic web module version and cxf web services project 2.5 as configuration; then I use the webservice wizard to generate the server, the windows closes, some files are generated (like web.xml and other xmls), but I don't get any java class.

Can anyone help me? I tried every combination of various configurations and versions with no luck.
I'm using Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Here's the console output:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 4 2017-09-29 15:02:32.291
!MESSAGE Exception loading preferences from: /pass-ricevute-pec/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/pass-ricevute-pec/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs' does not exist.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkExists(Resource.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkAccessible(Resource.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPreferences.load(ProjectPreferences.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPreferences.load(ProjectPreferences.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ProjectScope.getNode(ProjectScope.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getEclipsePreferences(JavaProject.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getOption(JavaProject.java:1657)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProjectElementInfo.computeNonJavaResources(JavaProjectElementInfo.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProjectElementInfo.getNonJavaResources(JavaProjectElementInfo.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getNonJavaResources(JavaProject.java:1650)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.getPackageFragmentRoots(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.StandardJavaElementContentProvider.getChildren(StandardJavaElementContentProvider.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.getChildren(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorContentProvider.getChildren(JavaNavigatorContentProvider.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorContentProvider.getPipelinedChildren(JavaNavigatorContentProvider.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.getPipelinedChildren(SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.pipelineChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.access$1(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$1.run(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.internalGetChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.getChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.JEE5ContentProvider$1.run(JEE5ContentProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.block(ModalContext.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.run(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.internalPerformFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:637)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.UserInputWizardPage.performFinish(UserInputWizardPage.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourcesWizard$DeleteResourcesRefactoringConfigurationPage.performFinish(DeleteResourcesWizard.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.performFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.okPressed(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.DeleteResourcesHandler.execute(DeleteResourcesHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommandInContext(LegacyHandlerService.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.LTKLauncher.runCommand(LTKLauncher.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.LTKLauncher.openDeleteWizard(LTKLauncher.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.DeleteResourceAction.run(DeleteResourceAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.reorg.DeleteAction.run(DeleteAction.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 368 2017-09-29 15:02:32.293
!MESSAGE Resource '/pass-ricevute-pec/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs' does not exist.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 4 4 2017-09-29 15:02:32.294
!MESSAGE Exception loading preferences from: D:/ws-giustizia/pass-ricevute-pec/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.service.prefs.BackingStoreException: Exception loading preferences from: /pass-ricevute-pec/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPreferences.load(ProjectPreferences.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPreferences.load(ProjectPreferences.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ProjectScope.getNode(ProjectScope.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getEclipsePreferences(JavaProject.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getOption(JavaProject.java:1657)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProjectElementInfo.computeNonJavaResources(JavaProjectElementInfo.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProjectElementInfo.getNonJavaResources(JavaProjectElementInfo.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getNonJavaResources(JavaProject.java:1650)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.getPackageFragmentRoots(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.StandardJavaElementContentProvider.getChildren(StandardJavaElementContentProvider.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.getChildren(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorContentProvider.getChildren(JavaNavigatorContentProvider.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorContentProvider.getPipelinedChildren(JavaNavigatorContentProvider.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.getPipelinedChildren(SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.pipelineChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.access$1(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$1.run(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.internalGetChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.getChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.JEE5ContentProvider$1.run(JEE5ContentProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.block(ModalContext.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.run(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.internalPerformFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:637)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.UserInputWizardPage.performFinish(UserInputWizardPage.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourcesWizard$DeleteResourcesRefactoringConfigurationPage.performFinish(DeleteResourcesWizard.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.performFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.okPressed(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.DeleteResourcesHandler.execute(DeleteResourcesHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommandInContext(LegacyHandlerService.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.LTKLauncher.runCommand(LTKLauncher.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.LTKLauncher.openDeleteWizard(LTKLauncher.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.DeleteResourceAction.run(DeleteResourceAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.reorg.DeleteAction.run(DeleteAction.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)

!ENTRY org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core 4 0 2017-09-29 15:03:16.566
!MESSAGE Could not auto-share project pass-ricevute-pec
!STACK 1
org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.SVNException: Provided SVN information does not match that on disk for project 'pass-ricevute-pec'.
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.resources.SVNWorkspaceRoot.setSharing(SVNWorkspaceRoot.java:206)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.SVNTeamProviderType$AutoShareJob.autoconnectSVNProject(SVNTeamProviderType.java:140)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.SVNTeamProviderType$AutoShareJob.run(SVNTeamProviderType.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core 4 4 2017-09-29 15:03:16.566
!MESSAGE Provided SVN information does not match that on disk for project 'pass-ricevute-pec'.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.core 4 0 2017-09-29 15:04:09.775
!MESSAGE 
WSDLToJava Error: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:294)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:184)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.required(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.AbstractField.annotateReference(AbstractField.java:192)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.AbstractField.annotate(AbstractField.java:161)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.AbstractFieldWithVar.createField(AbstractFieldWithVar.java:80)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.SingleField.<init>(SingleField.java:94)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.SingleField.<init>(SingleField.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.GenericFieldRenderer.generate(GenericFieldRenderer.java:69)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.DefaultFieldRenderer.generate(DefaultFieldRenderer.java:82)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generateFieldDecl(BeanGenerator.java:774)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generateClassBody(BeanGenerator.java:555)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:258)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:166)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:290)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:283)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:391)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:591)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:138)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:286)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef.required()
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1939)
    at com.sun.codemodel.TypedAnnotationWriter.invoke(TypedAnnotationWriter.java:112)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: @howlger it's the Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) but as I said, the servie was creted before, and with the same IDE

Comment: I found bug reports with similar stack traces which were old and closed. It is quite possible that the error occurred only under certain circumstances, but it is probably easier to update Eclipse than to find out these conditions and avoid them.